# How to set the first value of a select populated by a database table?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm a newbie in AngularJS and I want write a flexibile function to populate a select with a database table content. I can already fill the select, but I can not set the first value for it.

My code:

HTML :

```
<div id="super-regional-modal" ng-controller="RegionalController">
    <form name="regionalform" id="regionalform">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <span style="color:#DA1022;">* </span><label for="regionalInfoTipoRegional">Label Test</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="regionalInfoTipoRegional" name="regionalInfoTipoRegional" ng-model="regionalInfo.tipoRegional"  ng-init="regionalInfo.tipoRegional = populateSelect('select * from wrk_tests')" ng-options="tiporegional as tiporegional.cidade for tiporegional in populate_select_output track by tiporegional.id" ng-required="true"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS :

```
'use strict';
angular.module("acsApp").controller("RegionalController",  ["$scope", "$http", "$state", "$stateParams", "$timeout", "$sce", "toaster", function ($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $timeout, $sce, toaster){
$scope.populateSelect = function(sqlselect){
    $http.post("modulos/sistema/php/sys/fillDB.php", {"sqlselect" : sqlselect}
    ).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.populate_select_output = data.records;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.error(data);
    });
}
```

PHP :

```
    <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/".explode("/",$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])[1]."/functions.php");
    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/".explode("/",$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])[1]."/clsConnection.php");
    $cls_database   = new Database();
    $db             = $cls_database->getConnection();
    $data           = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $sqlselect      = $data->sqlselect;
    $stmt           = $db->prepare($sqlselect);
    $stmt->execute();
    $num            = $stmt->rowCount();
    $arr            = array();
    if($num>0){
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row);
            $arr[] = $row;
        }
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    echo json_encode(['records' => $arr]);
?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Sorry for my poor english. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to define a starting value for `regionalInfo` in your controller: `$scope.regionalInfo = {};` and then assign any of the retrieved records to `regionalInfo.tipoRegional`:

```
'use strict';
angular.module("acsApp").controller("RegionalController",  ["$scope", "$http", "$state", "$stateParams", "$timeout", "$sce", "toaster", function ($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $timeout, $sce, toaster){
$scope.regionalInfo = {};
$scope.populateSelect = function(sqlselect){
$http.post("modulos/sistema/php/sys/fillDB.php", {"sqlselect" : sqlselect}
  ).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    $scope.populate_select_output = data.records;
    $scope.regionalInfo.tipoRegional = $scope.populate_select_output[0]; // or 1, 2, etc...
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.error(data);
  });
}
```

and the `ng-init` could be changed to:

```
ng-init="populateSelect('select * from wrk_tests')"
```

Comment: Works like a charm!
Thank you mr_sudaca.